# How do you convert mtDNA sequences in FASTA to FSTAT format?

Tags: bioinformatics, population-biology, population-genetics

I've got control region sequence data from a population of shark and I'm looking to convert this from FASTA to FSTAT in order to calculated the effective population size of females. The software I want to use only accepts FSTAT or Genepop files.

Is it possible to convert FASTA to FSTAT or even Genepop?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [PGDSpider](http://www.cmpg.unibe.ch/software/PGDSpider/). The [inputs and outputs table](http://www.cmpg.unibe.ch/software/PGDSpider/#Input_and_output_formats) indicates that it supports conversion between FASTA and FSTAT formats, among many others.

Comment: I tried this, but the output file only showed that there was one locus. This is what made me wonder if it was possible to convert the file in the first place.

Comment: @WillPerry can you post an example of your FASTA? have you confirmed that it's formatted as expected? The manual might be helpful: http://www.cmpg.unibe.ch/software/PGDSpider/PGDSpider%20manual_vers%202-1-1-5.pdf